# How to integrate P(x,y) with X, Y, P(X,Y) being arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, numerical-integration

Basically, I have a set of data (4 columns) corresponding to various results from experiments.
The first, second and third columns are `x`, `y` and `p`; where `p` represents the probability `P(x, y)`. The last column is the error on `p`.

Now, what I want to find is

[image: \int P(x,y)dx]

Or

[image: \int P(x,y)dy]

That is, I'd like to perform a symbolic integration over my data, as I'd like to plot its result.

Some of my data:

```py
           x            y       p        ep
0   2.967330  2549.603175     1.0   1.00000
1   2.987216  2549.603175     0.0   0.00000
2   3.007102  2549.603175     0.0   0.00000
3   3.026989  2549.603175     3.0   1.73205
4   3.046875  2549.603175     0.0   0.00000
5   3.066761  2549.603175     4.0   2.00000
6   3.086648  2549.603175     1.0   1.00000
8   3.126420  2549.603175    10.0   3.16228
9   3.146307  2549.603175    24.0   4.89898
10  3.166193  2549.603175    35.0   5.91608
11  3.186080  2549.603175    71.0   8.42615
12  3.205966  2549.603175   118.0  10.86280
13  3.225852  2549.603175   188.0  13.71130
14  3.245739  2549.603175   337.0  18.35760
15  3.265625  2549.603175   475.0  21.79450
16  3.285511  2549.603175   706.0  26.57070
17  3.305398  2549.603175  1093.0  33.06060
18  3.325284  2549.603175  1536.0  39.19180
19  3.345170  2549.603175  2239.0  47.31810
```

In the x axis, data is equidistant of approximately `-0.01988637`.

In the Book "Python Companion to Data Science
" by D. Zinoviev that "Partial sums are a rough equivalent of an integral". I'd like to use this partial sums method, but I don't know how to.

Thanks in advance y'all.

Regards.

Comment: You say that you want to do numerical integration, but if you want \int P(x,y)dx, that would imply symbolic integration since y would still remain in the result. Are you sure that you don't want \int\int P(x,y) dx dy?

Comment: My bad @jjramsey, I'd like to do a symbolic integration, as I'd like to plot the result. I don't want a unique point... If that makes sense.

Comment: The simplest way is to just sum along over the first or second column (for integration over x and y respectively). But for the details one needs to know how the exactly x and y grids look like.

Comment: @Feodoran Thanks for you response. As stated in my post, the column representing x is the first, and the second is for y.  I've tried something like : 's = np.cumsum(x)' to sum over the first column. Then I try to plot it. I'd like to get something along the data plot of : https://ibb.co/xHZMKTj
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: One more thing: your data looks weird to me: If you have a function P(x,y) you should have a 2D array with Nx*Ny values, you however have 2 1D arrays with Nx+Ny values (not counting p and its error.)

Comment: with x and y grid I mean: how are the data points spaced? are they equidistant? if yes how much? this will scale the integral

Comment: @Feodoran My bad... They are equidistant of approximately : -0.01988637. (For x) 
To comment your previous question in regard to the shape of my data: 
I totally agree with you, maybe my phrasing is a bit odd as english is not my mother tongue. My supervisor (I'm doing an internship) said that the third column represent the probability P(x,y) however I agree with you, but the data set I have was not modified in any means... Should I reshape P(x,y) to yield at 2D Array ?

Comment: You cannot simply reshape it, you are missing data. Or you misunderstood something about your task. You need to clarify first what exactly you have there and what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized: all your y values are identical. So you can just sum the first column and mutliply by dx=0.01988. If you do cumsum(), then you get the definite integral with x as the upper limit of the integral (as a function of x).

Comment: Hi @BLDMoh, what's your domain of integration? You have a function that you want to integrate over a rectangle, or a circle, or a triangle, or the entire domain, or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your insight, your questions, your comments. I've found the solution and I'll explain it to help others.

The remark of @Feodoran gave me an idea. I decided to use pandas.
The following worked :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'....')
df.columns = ['x','y','p','ep']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df['p_x'] = df.iloc[:,[1]+[2]].sum(axis=1)
df.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'x', y = 'p_x', color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

Thanks again. I hope it will be useful for others as well.
Regards.

PS : As you may have guessed, the same can be done to obtain p_y.